# How to find the zeros of $z^{3} - iz^2 - z + i$

Tags: polynomials

I know that the function  $z^{3} - iz^2 - z + i$ has zeros at $z = -1$ and $z = 1$. How do I calculate all its zeros in the form $a + bi$?

Comment: You know $z^2-1$ divides it, so do polynomial division to find the first root.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$= z^2(z-i)-(z-i) = ...$$

Answer (score 1):

The three zeros are:

$$z_1= -1 = -1 + 0i, \, z_2= 1 = 1 + 0i,\,  z_3 =-i = 0+ (-1) i$$

as the product $z_1 z_2 z_3$ is equal to $-i$.